# Best way to migrate binary attachments from one org to another

Tags: data-loader, attachment, migration-tool, bulk-api, migration

Currently I am using **apex data loader** with  **bulk api enabled** and **batch size =1** .
But its giving me **failed to create batch** when i try to import 1000 files with each size around 100kb. 
I need to migrate around 100,000 attachments. Can't do it manually or in batch of 10 or 100.
What's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If Possible don't use  bulk API. Make Bulk Api disabled while using apex data loader. 
Bulk Api has lot of governor limits. And Try Also keeping batch size as low as 1 if upload attachment size is big.